# How to Change WrapWidth value of ToolBarOverflowPanel in WPF ToolBar

Tags: wpf, toolbar

Need to change WrapWidth value of ToolBarOverflowPanel in ToolBar.

Tried to set value for ToolBarOverflowPanel  WrapWidth using ToolBar Style.it shows error

```
<ToolBar Name="myToolBar" Height="50"  Band="1" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" >
            <ToolBar.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ToolBarOverflowPanel">
                    <Setter Property="WrapWidth" Value="20"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToolBar.Style>
            <Button Height="24" Width="24" Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black">

            </Button>
            <Button Height="24" Width="24"  Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black">

            </Button>
             <Grid>
                <Separator Margin="4">
                    <Separator.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                    </Separator.LayoutTransform>
                </Separator>
            </Grid>
            <Button Height="24" Width="24" Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black">

            </Button>
            <Button Height="24" Width="24"  Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black">

            </Button>
            <Grid>
                <Separator Margin="4">
                    <Separator.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                    </Separator.LayoutTransform>
                </Separator>
            </Grid>


            <Button Height="24" Width="24" Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black">

            </Button>
            <Button Height="24" Width="24"  Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black">


        </ToolBar>
```

Need to change wrapwidth value without changing toolbar template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that toolbar is using another controls in its template. If you want to override the default style/behavior then you need to look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/toolbar-styles-and-templates).